# largish webpage not working in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I am trying to save a large webpage locally and display it in a UIWebView.  When I save it, it makes a directory with several hundred files.  And when I load the index into UIWebView, I get a blank screen.  Interestingly, when I load it into browsers, it works in Firefox and in Safari, but not in Chrome.  I'm guessing this means that something in the webpage is not universally supported.  But what?  How can I find out?

I don't know HTML very well; is there some studying there that might help me?  If so, what?

Comment: MobileSafari is different from desktop OS browsers. But what do you want to achieve by saving a website in UIWebView ?

Comment: Well, what it really is is a powerpoint presentation, eventually due to become a series of presentations.  The client wants to put it into an app.  I tried loading the powerpoint into the UIWebView.  The presentation was visible, but the hyperlinks within it didn't work.  So I tried exporting it to html, resulting in my latest failure.  My end goal is to allow users to browse the presentation, links and all.  I may want to add videos, too -- but that part can wait.  You can think of it as an E-book taken to the next level with lots of interactivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I needed to do was put all the files inside a settings bundle.  The system was getting confused because paths get flattened when the app is copied into the app bundle.  By putting the files into a settings bundle, that was prevented.

Answer (score 0):

**For PowerPoint**

Try to convert the PowerPoint to a PDF. Just directly load the PDF instead loading a page containing a PowerPoint. If the user has installed iBook, he can even save the PDF to iBook directly.

**For Videos**

For videos, I think you can try using [VideoJS](http://www.videojs.com) video player and use a web page to contain it. If more complicated animations are involved other than videos, you may consider to make a full app instead of using UIWebView...